# slow render times when not active window

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine

When I'm rendering an animation or image, my times have been great on my new pc, like less than a minute or less than 30sec. But I've been noticing recently that when I'm rendering and the render window is not the active window it renders much slower and as soon as I select that window as the active render I see the samples rapidly jump up quickly. When I'm rendering an animation, I will watch a show in VLC and put that side by side to the render window and switch between the two windows to set one active over the other. It can't be the VLC player, cause when the render window is active the samples speed back up and the samples slow way down when the VLC is active.